# Reset IDs to logical order in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this, because some of the items have been removed:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
| id | nav_id | active | name   | link | ... |
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
| 1  |    1   |    1   | Item 1 | .......... |
| 6  |    2   |    1   | Item 2 | .......... |
| 15 |    1   |    1   | Item 3 | .......... |
| 16 |    3   |    1   | Item 4 | .......... |
| 75 |    1   |    1   | Item 5 | .......... |
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
```

As you can see, there are IDs in order `1, 6, 15, 16, 75` which can be sorted nicely. But what if I want them as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`? How can I reset their IDs, so it will be better to read? Just curious, not necessary.

Comment: i assume you are talking about reassigning primary keys?

Comment: For what reason would you want them as `1, 2, 3, 4`? If the answer is "because it's nicer" then you can be 100% sure you're doing nothing useful (there's a reason for those gaps).

Comment: I guess you could copy all the items to a new table.  But what possible reason could there be for something like this?  Why change how something is identified?  This seems like it would cause far more problems than it solves.

Comment: But why? To mess up the foreign keys?

Comment: @jarlh exactly, to mess up FKs, concurrency, writes and basically force everything that can go wrong - to go wrong. All because of some OCD problem. The `auto_increment` does not give **sequential numbers**. It increments sequentially, but it's job is to provide **unique** numbers. For numbering purposes, create another column and populate it via trigger.

Comment: Don't hate me, I was just asking if is something like that possible. Actually, I don't need to change their IDs, because everything works like it should, but that one would be good thing, if it won't do anything wrong.

Comment: Your question is based upon a false premise: that primary keys actually ('logically') represent distinct, sequential, numbers.  This is enhanced both by the fact that it's cheapest for the database to return a sequential value, and due to the type usually being integer.  Nothing could be further from the truth: surrogate ids should be considered the equivalent of pointer addresses - the actual value is meaningless, and you have no control over what the value is anyways.  A lot of trouble could be saved if such key columns disallowed math and ordering comparisons.

Comment: @debute: It's a perfectly valid *technical* question, sure.  But the best answer is ***don't do it***.  Note:  There *can* exist edge cases where there could be a very valid logic reason to do this.  Your last comment, however, strongly indicates that this is not such a case.  If the system works as intended and there's *no problem to be solved*, then performing such an invasive and dangerous operation on the data *just for the heck of it* seems like a *very bad idea*.

Comment: It's not hating, the thing is that this question pops up several times a day :)

Comment: Thank you all for your advices. @Mjh I was not able to find question like this, that's why I wrote my own, was looking through google and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT id, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn   
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS v
   ORDER BY id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.id = t2.rn;
```

**But**, I would advise *against* performing such an `UPDATE`. PK values should be immutable as their sole purpose is to *uniquely identify a table record*. If you want to change the way your table is displayed on the presentation layer, you can easily do so using a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I get `#1062 - Duplicate entry '33' for key 'PRIMARY'`. Works great for first 11 records, then it stopped. Now my table looks like this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/305afc7a2e9049d48630fb4cf5d1e90a.png - `55, 51` - wth?

Comment: @debute I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Can you setup and sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: I changed ID of that `55 and 51` and it worked then. Maybe problem was that these IDs were before lower IDs.